# Converting string(key:val) to xsl

Tags: xml, dictionary, xslt

Anyone got XSL code that'll convert a string in (key=val) format (see example)

Keep getting errors, when I try to run it that I can't diagnose due to lack of knowledge with the language.

Given: 
fr=me to=you do=command Num=1521739

Desire (in XSL):

```
<command>
    <Input>
        <Num>1521739</Num>
    </Input>
</command>
```

Comment: Does your XSLT processor support XSLT 2.0?

Comment: Unfortunately no, it is version 1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, given `$string` containing:

```
fr=me to=you do=command Num=1521739
```

you can extract the value of `do` as:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after($string, 'do='), ' ')"/>
```

and the value of `Num` as:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-after($string, 'Num=')"/>
```

If you don't know the order of the pairs, append a space to the string before extracting a value:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(concat($string, ' '), 'Num='), ' ')"/>
```

Similarly, if you suspect that a key can be contained in another key, e.g.

```
do=command undo=option
```

use a leading space to select the key unambiguously:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(concat(' ', $string, ' '), ' do='), ' ')"/>
```